# How can I use git to stage only one line in a file for commit, all from a script?

Tags: git, scripting

I'm writing a simple pre-commit git hook that updates the year in copyright headers for files that are staged for commit.

After modifying the line with the copyright, I would like the hook to stage that line so that it is part of the commit.  It can't just `git add` the whole file, because there may be other pre-existing changes in there that shouldn't be staged.

I don't see any options in the `git add` manual the let you stage specific lines.

I figure I could `git stash save --keep-index`, apply my change, `git add` the file, and then `git stash pop`, but that seems rather crude.  Any better approaches?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possible solution:

1. Before running your copyright-modification script, do a `git status` to get a list of the files it's about to commit. Save the list of files. Do a commit.
2. Then, stash the rest of the (unrelated) changes, and apply your script to the list of files saved above. Use `git commit --amend` to change the previous commit.
3. Finally, pop the stash to restore your index. Resolve conflicts if required.

I don't know of a way to tell `git add` to add only specific lines. How would you describe the lines to add? By line number? It seems that might be possible in a narrow set of circumstances, and not generally useful.

Comment: Ah, neat approach, though personally I'd prefer to wait on committing.

Answer (score 1):

You could patch the staged version of the file in a separate step, e.g.

```
blobid=$(git show :"$filepath" | copyright-filter | git hash-object -w --stdin)

if $? -eq 0; then

    git update-index --cacheinfo 100644 "$blobid" "$filepath" &&
    copyright-filter "$filepath"

fi
```

I've shamelessly assumed that your script is called `copyright-filter` and works as a filter or in place, depending on its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source to `git add --interactive` it looks like the way it modifies the index is with `git apply --cached`.  Assuming your copyright is the first hunk of any diff, make the change and use:

```
git diff -- file | 
awk 'second && /^@@/ {exit} /^@@/ {second=1} {print}' |
git apply --cached
```

Where that second line (the `awk` script grabs only the first diff hunk).  You could also construct the diff output by hand or use other rules to select the hunk.